# Zend Framework 3 Route Segment Parameter Problem

Tags: routes, zend-framework3, segment

In my module.config.php, i have a route configuration like below. At "*hizmetgetir*" route, i have parameter named "*search*", and constraints for it.
But i have a error like this: "The requested URL could not be matched by routing.".

When i change constraints  "*search*" with "*id*" i have no problem and i can catch route search parameter in my controller. in my opinion the parameter name and constraints name must be same.
What is the problem. Thanks.

**Old**

```php
'hizmetgetir' => [
    'type' => \Zend\Router\Http\Segment::class,
    'options' => [
        'route' => '/hizmetgetir[/:search]',
            'constraints' => [
            **'search' => '/[0-9a-zA-Z\s\'.;-]+/',**
        ],
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => Controller\ProfilController::class,
            'action' => 'ajaxhizmetgetir',
        ],
    ],
]
```

**New**

```php
'hizmetgetir' => [
    'type' => \Zend\Router\Http\Segment::class,
    'options' => [
        'route' => '/hizmetgetir[/:search]',
            'constraints' => [
            'id' => '/[0-9a-zA-Z\s\'.;-]+/',
        ],
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => Controller\ProfilController::class,
            'action' => 'ajaxhizmetgetir',
        ],
    ],
],
```

**My All Route conf.**

```php
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'rehberim' => [
            'type' => 'Literal',
            'options' => [
                // Change this to something specific to your module
                'route' => '/rehberim',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action' => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'profil' => [
            'type' => \Zend\Router\Http\Literal::class,
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/profil',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\ProfilController::class,
                    'action' => 'index',
                ],
            ],
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => [
                'hizmetgetir' => [
                    'type' => \Zend\Router\Http\Segment::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'route' => '/hizmetgetir[/:search]',
                            'constraints' => [
                            'id' => '/[0-9a-zA-Z\s\'.;-]+/',
                        ],
                        'defaults' => [
                            'controller' => Controller\ProfilController::class,
                            'action' => 'ajaxhizmetgetir',
                        ],

                    ],
                ],
                'profiluzman' => [
                    'type' => Segment::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'route' => '/profiluzman[/:id]',
                        'defaults' => [
                            'action' => 'profiluzman',
                        ],
                        'constraints' => [
                            'id' => '[0-9]+',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'profiluser' => [
                    'type' => \Zend\Router\Http\Segment::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'route' => '/profiluser[/:id]',
                        'defaults' => [
                            'action' => 'profiluser',
                        ],
                        'constraints' => [
                            'id' => '[0-9]+',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'profiladay' => [
                    'type' => \Zend\Router\Http\Segment::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'route' => '/profiladay[/:id]',
                        'constraints' => [
                            'id' => '[0-9]+',
                        ],
                        'defaults' => [
                            'action' => 'profiladay',
                        ],

                    ],
                ],
                'profilolustur' => [
                    'type' => \Zend\Router\Http\Segment::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'route' => '/profilolustur',
                        'defaults' => [
                            'action' => 'profilolustur',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question which is the not working code, but assuming "Old" is the not working, remove the slashes from your regular expression constraint (notice you don't have those on constraints on your other routes).

Comment: Please let us know which URL you are trying to reach.